# Java - Different between two timeMillis

Tags: java

How can i determine different between two `timeMillis` in minutes ?

my pseudo code is :

```
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
long b = MyClass.getPreviusTimeMillis();

double minutes = a - b = ?
```

Comment: `double c = (a - b)/6e4;` what's a problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to do division in Java, or are you asking how many milliseconds are in a minute?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) found in Java 5 and later.

```
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(a - b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference in minutes: `double d = (a - b)/60000.0`